# Setting up a graph database to query common properties across different types of nodes

Tags: database, database-design, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I am looking at using a graph database for some data from a relational database. The way the database is setup, information related to a single item is spread across multiple tables. From what I have read, it seems the way to go is to have a node type that corresponds to each table, and each entry in the table would be a node. Setting up edges between the nodes is what gets tricky.

For example, say I have a table of car parts:

```
| Part number | price | quantity in inventory |
```

Cars:

```
| make | model | price |
```

And a table of what car uses what part:

```
| model number | part number | quantity |
```

I would create a node for each car part, and a node for each car model. Then there would be a :uses relationship from the car model to each part it uses. That makes it easy to get all the parts used in a particular car, or what cars contain a specific part.

What if I wanted to find all cars and car parts that have a certain price? (Ignoring in this example that car parts tend not to cost as much as a car) I.E. Querying by shared properties? A query that goes through, examining each node, and accepting or rejecting the node if the price does not match seems like it would not scale well. If you had millions of parts in your database, wouldn't that be very slow?

The way to get around this that I can think of would be to create a price node for each unique price, and make a link between each part and its price. But it seems like that approach would eventually leave you with a node for every unique property value, and that seems excessive too.

When taking data from a relational database to put into a graph database, and you want to be able to query based on common properties across different types of nodes, what is the best way to go about setting up your nodes and relationships?